# PHP session is not persisting in pagination

Tags: php, session, pagination

PHP session variable loses data when used in a page that uses pagination script.

I'm using PHP pagination using `$_GET[]`. When the url looks like `example.com/folder/index.php?page=2` the session does not work. But it works fine when the url is like `example.com/folder/index.php`.

How can I keep the session data persistent when using along with pagination script?

### Edit:

Yes I am using `session_start()` at the top of the page.

```
session_start();
$page = (!isset($_GET['page']))? 1 : (int)$_GET['page'];

$prev_link = ($page - 1);
$next_link = ($page + 1);

/* Max results per page */
$max_results = 20;

/* Calculate the offset */
$from = (($page * $max_results) - $max_results);

$stmt3 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM my_table");
$stmt3->execute();
$row3 = $stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

if(!$row3)
 {
  die('Could not get data.');
 }

$total_results = $row3[0];
$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $max_results);
$pagination = '';

/* Create a PREV link if there is one */
if($page > 1)
  {
   $pagination .= "<a class='pagination_link' href='http://example.com/folder/index.php?page=".$prev_link."' style='padding:1%;'>Previous</a>";
  }
 /* Loop through the total pages */
for($i = max(1, $page - 5); $i <= min($page + 5, $total_pages); $i++)
  {
   if(($page) == $i)
     {
     $pagination .= "<span style='padding:1%;font-weight:bold;'>$i</span>";
     }
   else
    {
    $pagination .= "<a class='pagination_link' href='index.php?page=".$i."' style='padding:1%;'>".$i."</a>";
    }
  }

 /* Print NEXT link if there is one */
if($page < $total_pages)
  {
   $pagination .= "<a class='pagination_link' href='http://example.com/folder/index.php?page=".$next_link."' style='padding:1%;'> Next</a>";
  }
```

Comment: are you sure that session_start(); is at the top of each page?

Comment: I've post the code & using `session_start()` at top of each page.

Answer (score 0):

In each of your php pages that you wish to utilise PHP Sessions, please make sure that the following line is at the top of your PHP pages

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

This ensures that session data is carried across pages